# Cutting value from column A and pasting it in previous row's column B

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I need help writing a VBA script for Excel 2010 (Windows 7).

I have thousands of entries set like this:

```
Data ID Number1 (A1)
Data Article Name1 (A2)
Data ID Number2 (A3)
Data Article Name2 (A4)
Data ID Number 3 (A5)
Data Article Name 3 (A6)
Data ID Number 3 (A7)
Data Article Name 3 (A8)
```

=============

And I need it to look like this:

```
Data ID Number1 (A1)     Data Article Name1 (B1)
Data ID Number2 (A2)     Data Article Name2 (B2)
Data ID Number 3 (A3)    Data Article Name3 (B3)
Data ID Number 4 (A4)    Data Article Name4 (B4)
```

I need to be able to do this as an automatic process, as I have a large amount of entries.

*edit* changed the article to make it a bit clearer!

Comment: What have you tried? If you don't know where to begin, start by using the macro recorder.

Comment: In B1 put `=IF(MOD(ROW(A2),2)=0,A2,"")` and fill down.

Comment: @Scott, I tried but it did not work.

Comment: @TimWilliams that did not work because my data is not 1-10000, since I had filters

Comment: Then you should update your question to clarify your *exact* situation

Comment: it looks like this comment by rich on another forum worked!

Comment: I was able to get a script that works, but it won't let me post it so early.

Answer (score 0):

Will this work?  Wasn't sure from your question if you wanted the original row containing Article deleted or not.

```
Dim row
Dim lastRow
lastRow = 8

For row = lastRow To 2 Step -1
    If row Mod 2 = 0 Then
        ' copy data
        Cells(row - 1, 2) = Cells(row, 1).Value
        ' delete row
        Cells(row, 1).EntireRow.Delete
    End If
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

This macro will iterate through all cells in Column A. If the cell row is even, then the value will be moved over to Column B (at an offset of (-1,1). The cell is then added to a range which is deleted after the For Loop is complete.

```
Sub test()

    Dim i As Range
    Dim delrows As Range

    For Each i In Intersect(ActiveSheet.UsedRange, Range("A:A"))
        If (i.Row Mod 2) = 0 Then
            i.Offset(-1, 1).Value = i.Value

            If delrows Is Nothing Then
                Set delrows = i
            Else
                Set delrows = Union(i, delrows)
            End If
        End If
    Next i

    delrows.EntireRow.Delete


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This code is a bit simple but should do the trick

```
Sub Shift()
'Set to your first value you want shifted. In your example A2.
Range("A2").Select

    Do

        ActiveCell.Cut
        ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 1).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, -1).Select
        ActiveCell.EntireRow.Select
        ActiveCell.Delete

    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select

    Loop Until ActiveCell.Value = "" And ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Value = ""
End Sub
```

Have a great day!